# R dplyr method to replace all empty factors with NA

Tags: r, dplyr

Instead of writing and reading a dataframe to fill all empty factors in this method,

```
na.strings=c("","NA")
```

I wanted to just apply a function to all the columns and substitute the empties with NA. I've selected the factor columns so far but don't know what to do next.

```
df %>% select_if(is.factor) %>% ....
```

How would I be able to do this, preferably with dplyr and/or apply methods

Comment: Please provide some example data.

Comment: `df %>% mutate_if(is.factor, na_if, '')`

Comment: @alistaire - I needed to do: `df %>% mutate_if(is.factor, na_if, y='')` to get it to work.

Comment: @thelatemail Hm, it worked fine unnamed for me on the devel version with rlang. Naming parameters is safer anyway, I guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `mutate_if`

```
df <- df %>%
         mutate_if(is.factor, funs(factor(replace(., .=="", NA))))
```

With `dplyr 0.8.0`, we can also do

```
df %>% 
    mutate_if(is.factor, na_if, y = "")
```

or change the `funs` (which is getting deprecated to `list` as @Frederick mentioned in the comments)

```
df %>%
   mutate_if(is.factor, list(~ na_if(., "")))
```

---

Or using `base R` we can assign the specific `levels` to `NA`

```
j1 <- sapply(df, is.factor)
df[j1] <- lapply(df[j1], function(x) {is.na(x) <- levels(x)==""; x})
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("", "A", "B", ""), col2 = c("A", "", "", "C"),
         col3 = 1:4)
```

Comment: As of dplyr 0.8.0 the first alternative should be:

df <- df %>%
         mutate_if(is.factor, list(~factor(replace(., .=="", NA))))

Comment: @Frederick  Thanks for notifying, I updated.  I used `na_if` to make it shorter.